# Level selector using andEngine. Every thing is black?

Tags: android, andengine, game-engine

I started working on AndEngine and I have learnt a lot but i am stuck in creating levels selector for my game. I know this is something to do with getTextureManager() as i went through this when i am trying to attach ITextureRegion to my sprite object, that i solved but this time i am going nowhere for last day.

mainActivity.java

```
import org.andengine.engine.camera.Camera;
import org.andengine.engine.options.EngineOptions;
import org.andengine.engine.options.ScreenOrientation;
import org.andengine.engine.options.WakeLockOptions;
import org.andengine.engine.options.resolutionpolicy.FillResolutionPolicy;
import org.andengine.entity.scene.Scene;
import org.andengine.entity.scene.background.Background;
import org.andengine.opengl.font.FontFactory;
import org.andengine.opengl.texture.ITexture;
import org.andengine.opengl.texture.TextureManager;
import org.andengine.opengl.texture.atlas.bitmap.BitmapTextureAtlas;
import org.andengine.opengl.texture.atlas.bitmap.BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory;
import org.andengine.opengl.texture.atlas.bitmap.BuildableBitmapTextureAtlas;
import org.andengine.opengl.texture.atlas.bitmap.source.IBitmapTextureAtlasSource;
import org.andengine.opengl.texture.atlas.buildable.builder.BlackPawnTextureAtlasBuilder;
import org.andengine.opengl.texture.atlas.buildable.builder.ITextureAtlasBuilder.TextureAtlasBuilderException;
import org.andengine.opengl.texture.region.ITextureRegion;
import org.andengine.opengl.texture.region.TextureRegion;
import org.andengine.ui.activity.SimpleBaseGameActivity;
import org.andengine.util.color.Color;

import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.util.Log;



public class Main_Activity extends SimpleBaseGameActivity {
    EngineOptions engine;
    Camera mCamera;
    private static final int WIDTH = 800;
    private static final int HEIGHT = 480;
    LevelSelector ls;
    Scene mScene;
    public org.andengine.opengl.font.Font   mFont;
    ITextureRegion mTextureRegion;

    @Override
    public EngineOptions onCreateEngineOptions() {  
        mCamera = new Camera(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        engine = new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE_FIXED, new FillResolutionPolicy(), mCamera);
        engine.setWakeLockOptions(WakeLockOptions.SCREEN_ON);

        return engine;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreateResources() {
    BuildableBitmapTextureAtlas mBitmapTextureAtlas = new BuildableBitmapTextureAtlas(this.getTextureManager() ,32 , 32);

        mTextureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(mBitmapTextureAtlas, this, "marble.png");

        try {
            mBitmapTextureAtlas.build(new BlackPawnTextureAtlasBuilder<IBitmapTextureAtlasSource, BitmapTextureAtlas>(0, 1, 1));
            mBitmapTextureAtlas.load();
        } catch (TextureAtlasBuilderException e) {
            Log.e("", ""+e);
        }

        this.mFont = FontFactory.create(this.getFontManager(), this.getTextureManager(), 256, 256, Typeface.create(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.BOLD), 32);
        this.mFont.load();
    }

    @Override
    protected Scene onCreateScene() {
        mScene = new Scene();
        mScene.setBackground(new Background(0.09804f, 0.6274f, 0.8784f));
        ls = new LevelSelector(5, 2, WIDTH, HEIGHT, mScene, mEngine);
        ls.createTiles(mTextureRegion, mFont);
        ls.show();
        return mScene;
    }

}
```

LayerSelector.java

```
import org.andengine.engine.options.EngineOptions;
import org.andengine.entity.Entity;
import org.andengine.entity.scene.Scene;
import org.andengine.entity.sprite.Sprite;
import org.andengine.entity.text.Text;
import org.andengine.input.touch.TouchEvent;
import org.andengine.opengl.font.Font;
import org.andengine.opengl.texture.region.ITextureRegion;
import org.andengine.opengl.texture.region.TextureRegion;


import android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService.Engine;

public class LevelSelector extends Entity {
    /* Level selector layer properties */
    private final int COLUMNS = 6;
    private final int ROWS = 6;

    /* Level selector tile properties */
    private final int TILE_DIMENSION = 50;
    private final int TILE_PADDING = 15;

    private final Scene mScene;
    private final org.andengine.engine.Engine mEngine;

    /*
     * The mChapter variable can allow each LevelSelector object to contain
     * level tiles which begin levels in different chapters.
     */
    private final int mChapter;

    /* Variable containing the current max level unlocked */
    private final int mMaxLevel;

    /* Camera width and height are needed for the layout */
    private final int mCameraWidth;
    private final int mCameraHeight;

    /* Initial x/y coordinates used for tile positioning */
    private final float mInitialX;
    private final float mInitialY;

    /*
     * Variable which defines whether the LevelSelector is hidden or visible
     */
    private boolean mHidden = true;

    /**
     * The LevelSelector object can be used to display a grid of level tiles for
     * user selection.
     * 
     * @param pMaxLevel
     *            Current max unlocked level.
     * @param pChapter
     *            Chapter/world number of this particular LevelSelector.
     * @param pCameraWidth
     *            Camera object's width value.
     * @param pCameraHeight
     *            Camera object's height value.
     * @param pScene
     *            The Scene in which the LevelSelector will be displayed on.
     * @param pEngine
     *            AndEngine's mEngine object.
     */
    public LevelSelector(final int pMaxLevel, final int pChapter,
            final int pCameraWidth, final int pCameraHeight,
            final Scene pScene, final org.andengine.engine.Engine pEngine) {
        /* Initialize member variables */
        this.mScene = pScene;
        this.mEngine = pEngine;
        this.mChapter = pChapter;
        this.mMaxLevel = pMaxLevel;
        this.mCameraWidth = pCameraWidth;
        this.mCameraHeight = pCameraHeight;

        /*
         * Obtain the initial tile's X coordinate by subtracting half of the
         * entire level selector width including all tiles and padding from the
         * center of the Scene
         */
        final float halfLevelSelectorWidth = ((TILE_DIMENSION * COLUMNS) + TILE_PADDING
                * (COLUMNS - 1)) * 0.5f;
        this.mInitialX = (this.mCameraWidth * 0.5f) - halfLevelSelectorWidth;

        /* Same math as above applies to the Y coordinate */
        final float halfLevelSelectorHeight = ((TILE_DIMENSION * ROWS) + TILE_PADDING
                * (ROWS - 1)) * 0.5f;
        this.mInitialY = (this.mCameraHeight * 0.5f) + halfLevelSelectorHeight;
        mEngine.getTextureManager();
    }

    /**
     * Create the level tiles with a customized ITextureRegion representation as
     * well as a customized Font.
     * 
     * @param pTextureRegion
     *            The ITextureRegion to supply each of the level tiles.
     * @param pFont
     *            The Font to be displayed by Text written on the tiles,
     *            specifying tile level number for example.
     */
    public void createTiles(final ITextureRegion pTextureRegion,
            final org.andengine.opengl.font.Font pFont) {

        /* Temp coordinates for placing level tiles */
        float tempX = this.mInitialX + TILE_DIMENSION * 0.5f;
        float tempY = this.mInitialY - TILE_DIMENSION * 0.5f;

        /* Current level of the tile to be placed */
        int currentTileLevel = 1;

        /*
         * Loop through the Rows, adjusting tempY coordinate after each
         * iteration
         */
        for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {

            /*
             * Loop through the column positions, placing a LevelTile in each
             * column
             */
            for (int o = 0; o < COLUMNS; o++) {

                final boolean locked;

                /* Determine whether the current tile is locked or not */
                if (currentTileLevel <= mMaxLevel) {
                    locked = false;
                } else {
                    locked = true;
                }

                /* Create a level tile */
                LevelTile levelTile = new LevelTile(tempX, tempY, locked,
                        currentTileLevel, pTextureRegion, pFont);

                /*
                 * Attach the level tile's text based on the locked and
                 * currentTileLevel variables pass to its constructor
                 */
                levelTile.attachText();

                /* Register & Attach the levelTile object to the LevelSelector */
                mScene.registerTouchArea(levelTile);
                this.attachChild(levelTile);

                /* Increment the tempX coordinate to the next column */
                tempX = tempX + TILE_DIMENSION + TILE_PADDING;

                /* Increment the level tile count */
                currentTileLevel++;
            }

            /* Reposition the tempX coordinate back to the first row (far left) */
            tempX = mInitialX + TILE_DIMENSION * 0.5f;

            /* Reposition the tempY coordinate for the next row to apply tiles */
            tempY = tempY - TILE_DIMENSION - TILE_PADDING;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Display the LevelSelector on the Scene.
     */
    public void show() {

        /* Register as non-hidden, allowing touch events */
        mHidden = false;

        /* Attach the LevelSelector the the Scene if it currently has no parent */
        if (!this.hasParent()) {
            mScene.attachChild(this);
        }

        /* Set the LevelSelector to visible */
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    /**
     * Hide the LevelSelector on the Scene.
     */
    public void hide() {

        /* Register as hidden, disallowing touch events */
        mHidden = true;

        /* Remove the LevelSelector from view */
        this.setVisible(false);
    }

    public class LevelTile extends Sprite {

        /*
         * The LevelTile should keep track of level number and lock status. Feel
         * free to add additional data within level tiles
         */
        private final boolean mIsLocked;
        private final int mLevelNumber;
        private final org.andengine.opengl.font.Font mFont;
        private Text mTileText;

        /*
         * Each level tile will be sized according to the constant
         * TILE_DIMENSION within the LevelSelector class
         */
        public LevelTile(float pX, float pY, boolean pIsLocked,
                int pLevelNumber, ITextureRegion pTextureRegion, org.andengine.opengl.font.Font pFont) {
            super(pX, pY, LevelSelector.this.TILE_DIMENSION,
                    LevelSelector.this.TILE_DIMENSION, pTextureRegion,
                    LevelSelector.this.mEngine.getVertexBufferObjectManager());

            /* Initialize the necessary variables for the LevelTile */
            this.mFont = pFont;
            this.mIsLocked = pIsLocked;
            this.mLevelNumber = pLevelNumber;
        }

        /* Method used to obtain whether or not this level tile represents a
         * level which is currently locked */
        public boolean isLocked() {
            return this.mIsLocked;
        }

        /* Method used to obtain this specific level tiles level number */
        public int getLevelNumber() {
            return this.mLevelNumber;
        }

        /*
         * Attach the LevelTile's text to itself based on whether it's locked or
         * not. If not, then the level number will be displayed on the level
         * tile.
         */
        public void attachText() {

            String tileTextString = null;

            /* If the tile's text is currently null... */
            if (this.mTileText == null) {

                /*
                 * Determine the tile's string based on whether it's locked or
                 * not
                 */
                if (this.mIsLocked) {
                    tileTextString = "Locked";
                } else {
                    tileTextString = String.valueOf(this.mLevelNumber);
                }

                /* Setup the text position to be placed in the center of the tile */
                final float textPositionX = LevelSelector.this.TILE_DIMENSION * 0.5f;
                final float textPositionY = textPositionX;

                /* Create the tile's text in the center of the tile */
                this.mTileText = new Text( textPositionX,
                        textPositionY, this.mFont,
                        tileTextString, tileTextString.length(),
                        LevelSelector.this.mEngine
                                .getVertexBufferObjectManager());

                /* Attach the Text to the LevelTile */
                this.attachChild(mTileText);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent,
                float pTouchAreaLocalX, float pTouchAreaLocalY) {

            /* If the LevelSelector is not hidden, proceed to execute the touch
             * event */
            if (!LevelSelector.this.mHidden) {

                /* If a level tile is initially pressed down on */
                if (pSceneTouchEvent.isActionDown()) {
                    /* If this level tile is locked... */
                    if (this.mIsLocked) {
                        /* Tile Locked event... */
                        LevelSelector.this.mScene.getBackground().setColor(
                                org.andengine.util.color.Color.RED);
                    } else {
                        /* Tile unlocked event... This event would likely prompt
                         * level loading but without getting too complicated we
                         * will simply set the Scene's background color to green */
                        LevelSelector.this.mScene.getBackground().setColor(
                                org.andengine.util.color.Color.GREEN);

                        /**
                         * Example level loading:
                         *      LevelSelector.this.hide();
                         *      SceneManager.loadLevel(this.mLevelNumber);
                         */
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return super.onAreaTouched(pSceneTouchEvent, pTouchAreaLocalX,
                    pTouchAreaLocalY);
        }
    }
}
```

FYI, this code belongs to code bundle in Android game development using AndEngine cookbook.
I have edited few variables like font and engine , but i have't changed the logic or flow of program.

Now when I run this I get the below screen[image]

Answer (score 3):

Alright i solved my problem, its was the padding i was using, it should't be there.

```
 try {
            mBitmapTextureAtlas.build(new BlackPawnTextureAtlasBuilder<IBitmapTextureAtlasSource, BitmapTextureAtlas>(0, 1, 1));
            mBitmapTextureAtlas.load();
        } catch (TextureAtlasBuilderException e) {
            Log.e("", ""+e);
        }
```

it should be

try {

```
    mBitmapTextureAtlas.build(new BlackPawnTextureAtlasBuilder<IBitmapTextureAtlasSource, BitmapTextureAtlas>(0, 0, 0));
    mBitmapTextureAtlas.load();
} catch (TextureAtlasBuilderException e) {
    Log.e("", ""+e);
}
```

Comment: +1 for solving this yourself - and AFAIK, there is nothing wrong with accepting your own answer